# Proof of Noether normalisation lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have a question about a step in the proof of Noether normalisation lemma (Prop. 1.9, page 29 in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry":

[image]

I don't understand why $P(X)$ can expressed as $\alpha X_n ^e + Q_1 (S) X_n ^{e-1} + ... Q_e (S)$, if we can choose $m \in \mathbb{N}^n$ with the conditions in red taged lines.

Comment: Have you tried the slightly easier (at least intuitively) version of the theorem, where you assume $k$ is infinite and take $S_i=X_i+c_iX_n$ and show that for general choices of $c_i$, $P(X)$ is monic (upto units in $k$) in $X_n$? If you haven't, I suggest you try that first to warm up.

Comment: I think that I know now where it does come from. Because $P(X)$ has the term $a_{\nu} X^{\nu}$ therefore $P(X)$ expressed in $S_i$ and $X_n$ must have the term $a_{\nu} S^{\nu_1} S^{\nu_2} ... S^{\nu_{n-1}} X^{\nu_n}$. Multiply out and utilise the max condition for m (in $S_i$) provide the explanation